# Custom Serialization based on User defined value

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I've a **pojo** :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Item
{
   String name;

   Long baseId;

   @JsonIgnore
   String status;
}
```

I'm using this Java Object for **GET**, **POST** and **PUT** api calls. I've used **@JsonIgnore** annotations To avoid serializations(So it wont serialize for *PUT* and *POST* request but i got for *GET* request). Now I'm in need that baseId should be serialized for **POST** request and not for **PUT** request. Please suggest me the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [the Jackson Json views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews). Basically, you replace the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the Jackson view annotation with a view type and enable it depending on the context. Here is an example for a plain object mapper:

```
public class JacksonView {

    public static interface View1 {
    }

    public static interface View2 {
    }

    public static class Bean {
        @JsonView(View1.class)
        public final String field1;
        @JsonView(View2.class)
        public final String field2;
        public final String field3;

        public Bean(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
            this.field3 = field3;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Bean bean = new Bean("a", "b", "c");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper
                .writer()
                .withView(View2.class)
                .writeValueAsString(bean));

    }

}
```

Output:

```
{"field2":"b","field3":"c"}
```

To make it work in JAX-RS you should enable the specific view by annotating your HTTP method resources as described [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers#annotations-on-resources). Example:

```
@GET
@JsonView(View1.class)
public Bean doGet() {...}

@POST
@JsonView(View2.class)
public void doPost(Bean bean) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We should have a practice of reusing Objectmapper http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance#A1._Reuse_when_appropriate. Am preparing client library. So  it most to give simple and optimistic.